# Pretty Photo not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

Why is my implementation of Pretty Photo not firing on the image gallery on this page?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
 });

<a href="gala2016-photos/photo1-large.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title=""><img src="gala2016-photos/photo1-small.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="gala2016-photos/photo2-large.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title=""><img src="gala2016-photos/photo2-small.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.$.prettyPhoto.initialize (http://www.christielakekids.com/_includes/javascript/jquery.prettyPhoto.js:57:214)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js:5095:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js:4766:28)`

Comment: `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg: "http://www.christielakekids.com/gala2016-photos/photo7-large.jpg".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library prettyPhoto needs jquery $.browser but it's deprecated.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Try updating the prettyPhoto library